# Photos app on mac won't sync OSX Big Sur

Tags: mac, icloud, big-sur, photos.app

I've searched everywhere online and cannot seem to find an answer to my issue with the Photos app on Mac. Currently the Photos app is blank with no contents, no synced photos, nothing... every page and tab is blank.

On my mac I'm signed into the same apple-id that I use on my iPhone and I have about 2GB of photos.

This is what I see on the photos app on mac:

[image: iCloud Image]

In order to turn on iCloud photos, online instructions say to go to "System Preferences" -> "Apple ID" to turn on iCloud photos

But when I go there, its already turned on:

[image: Apple ID page in System Preferences]

I've tried the rebuild Photos app library option by launching the app with Command + Option selected. It hasn't worked.

My setup:

- Mac OSX Big Sur
- iPhone 8 iOS 14.4
- Both signed into the same apple id with icloud photos turned on.

I feel like an insane person.. can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you see photos on the web that is https://icloud.com

Comment: Yes I can - lots of photos